# Backbone.js fetch collection from it's initialize method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

someone building an app for us, provided me the code so I could go through it,
and I noticed this, which at first seems OK, and even nice to let the collection manage his data
but after a while I started thinking about the possible pitfalls in this idea

so: 
is it good practice to fetch a collection's data from it's own initialize method.

for example:

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    url: '/books',

    initialize: function(){
        // do some logic here

        // if collection is empty, fetch from server
        if(this.size() == 0)
            this.fetch();
    }

});
```

i ask this because i feel it might be a problem in the following situation:

suppose we are in a routeAction:

```
books: function() {
    var books = new Books();
    var bookList = new BookList({ collection: books });
}
```

isn't this situation possible failure, if the fetch would be faster than the initialization of the view, where the view would have bound to a reset event, the reset would have triggered way before the initialize of the view had been executed?

am I wrong on this, or should I submit a ticket to get this fixed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While in practice the initialization of the view will most likely occur before `fetch()` is complete (and you would bind `render()` to `reset` not `initialize()`) it's a really bad idea to rely on the order of async operations anyway. In other words, your code should be written in a way that makes order irrelevant.

I have seen `fetch()` being called in `initialize()` in various projects. I still think it's undesirable and bad practice. Explicitly fetching when you need to also has these advantages:

1. You can do it when you need to, not every time you create a new collection.
2. You can do certain things in order if you want to:

   For example, you can initialize your view and render only once you have fetched.

   ```
   var bookList, books = new Books();
   var p = books.fetch();
   p.done(function () {
     bookList = new BookList({collection: books });
     bookList.render();
   });
   ```
3. It makes testing easier.

Comment: thanks for the insight, I will ask him to edit the code accordingly. you are right about several points, though i believe in his case the current app does only create 1 collection, so loading each time a collection is created isn't really an issue, though i can see it becomming an issue when the app is going in a version 2 or 3 later next year, other collections might be added.

Comment: As you imply in your question, it's a matter of using the correct approach. Fetching inside `initialize` will not produce an error. It's just ineffective, ugly and *in principle* wrong.

Comment: @mu-is-too-short Thank you! I spent 20 mins trying to figure out code blocks inside lists and failed. I miss my reST...

Comment: I do this in a SyncPanel component. For example panel.load({tasks: {fetch: [books]}, sync: function doSomeThingWithBooks (){...}}). It is much easier to handle parallel calls and errors that way...